# WCF Web Service can't access service name in Web Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web, service

This is my first web service and I am trying to follow a tutorial on creating a custom authentication for a web service,  am stuck as I'm getting this error:

The value 'WcfOrderingService.Services.AuthenticationTokenService' is invalid according to its datatype 'serviceNameType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

web config:

```
      <service name ="WcfOrderingService.Services.AuthenticationTokenService"
           behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviourHttp">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WcfOrderingService.AuthenticationTokenServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfOrderingService.Services.AuthenticationTokenService.Authenticate" />
  </service>
```

.svc.cs -

```
namespace WcfOrderingService.Services
{
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class AuthenticationTokenService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    public string Authenticate(Credentials creds)
    {
        ICredentialsValidator validator = new CredentialsValidator();
        if (validator.IsValid(creds))
            return new TokenBuilder().Build(creds);
        throw new InvalidCredentialException("Invalid credentials");
    }
}
```

}

I have tried most things I have found online, variations of the service name etc but cant find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reference to the service isn't working properly anymore. There can be several reason's for this. 
The solution will be to first remove the servicereference and then add it again.

Comment: Thanks, but if I even start a whole new WCF Service Application project then add a WCF Service (Ajax-enabled) service - it gives me the same error.

Comment: Ah, I think that the configuration is not correct. Does it work when you change the contract attribute of the endpoint into WcfOrderingService.Services.AuthenticationTokenService ?

Comment: It doesn't work intellisense doesnt pick it up either, the default service1 does though.

Answer (score 0):

The following was causing errors in my Web.config

```
<service name="case_info">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="case_infoAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="ICase_Info" />
</service>
```

I appeared to have solved the problem by moving my service and contract (interface) into a namespace.

```
<service name="mynamesp.case_info">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="case_infoAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="mynamesp.ICase_Info" />
</service>
```

It turned out that as long as you leave the Web.config open when running the project then, strangely, all would run fine. I ended up taking the service out of the namespace and not implementing an interface at all.

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="http://edwardo.com/services/")>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class case_info

    <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
    <OperationContract()>
    Public Function GetCasePopup(CaseID As Int32) As CasePopupInfo
        Return CasePopup.GetCasePopup(CaseID)
    End Function

End Class
```

The following 2 items in Web.config were vital to getting this working over https.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
            <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name=".svc" verb="*" path="*.svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

So, maybe getting a bit off subject but perhaps this will help someone.